# ListFragment shows empty text when the list is not empty

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-listfragment, android-loadermanager

I am trying to make a LoaderManager list backwards compatible to Android 2.1. The list is loading fine but the @id/android:empty message shows even when there are items clearly visible in the list.

I have looked at a number of solutions on StackOverflow that use setEmptyView() and setEmptyText() but couldn't get them to work.

Here is the code for the ListFragment. I have been combining code from various http://www.vogella.com/ tutorials.

```
package com.example.contentprov;

import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.contentprov.data.MyTodoContentProvider;
import com.example.contentprov.data.TodoTable;

/*
 * TodosOverviewActivity displays the existing todo items
 * in a list
 * 
 * You can create new ones via the ActionBar entry "Insert"
 * You can delete existing ones via a long press on the item
 */

public class TodoOverviewFragment extends ListFragment implements
LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, OnItemClickListener {
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.todo_list);
        fillData();
    }

    // Opens the second activity if an entry is clicked
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), TodoDetailActivity.class);
        Uri todoUri = Uri.parse(MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI + "/" + id);
        i.putExtra(MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, todoUri);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private void fillData() {

        // Fields from the database (projection)
        // Must include the _id column for the adapter to work
        String[] from = new String[] { TodoTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY };
        // Fields on the UI to which we map
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.label };

        getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.todo_row, null, from,
                to, 0);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // Creates a new loader after the initLoader () call
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String[] projection = { TodoTable.COLUMN_ID, TodoTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY };
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
        return cursorLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        adapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        // data is not available anymore, delete reference
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), TodoDetailActivity.class);
        Uri todoUri = Uri.parse(MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI + "/" + id);
        i.putExtra(MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, todoUri);

        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Here is the XML file for the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_todos" />

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: The solution was to combine Eluvatar and dymmeh's answers. Here is the new version of the ListFragment.

```
package com.example.contentprov;

import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.contentprov.data.MyTodoContentProvider;
import com.example.contentprov.data.TodoTable;

/*
 * TodosOverviewActivity displays the existing todo items
 * in a list
 * 
 * You can create new ones via the ActionBar entry "Insert"
 * You can delete existing ones via a long press on the item
 */

public class TodoOverviewFragment extends ListFragment implements
LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, OnItemClickListener {
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fillData();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_list,
                container, false);
        return view;
    }

    // Opens the second activity if an entry is clicked
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), TodoDetailActivity.class);
        Uri todoUri = Uri.parse(MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI + "/" + id);
        i.putExtra(MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, todoUri);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private void fillData() {

        // Fields from the database (projection)
        // Must include the _id column for the adapter to work
        String[] from = new String[] { TodoTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY };
        // Fields on the UI to which we map
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.label };

        getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.todo_row, null, from,
                to, 0);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // Creates a new loader after the initLoader () call
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String[] projection = { TodoTable.COLUMN_ID, TodoTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY };
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
        return cursorLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        adapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        // data is not available anymore, delete reference
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), TodoDetailActivity.class);
        Uri todoUri = Uri.parse(MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI + "/" + id);
        i.putExtra(MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, todoUri);

        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: uh you're setting the content view on the activity from the fragment?! why?

Comment: It was in a ListActivity but ListActivity was not compatible with LoaderManager. LoaderManager required a ListFragment to be used instead (when using getSupportLoaderManager for backwards compatibility). I am fairly new to Android. Does that answer your question?

Comment: yes you should take a look at using http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html, I've not used the `ListFragment` specifically but you should override `OnCreateView` and substitute your custom layout there as that's why you're not seeing your list view at all (add a text view at the top and just try getting that visible), as for the rest well... I've never used LoaderManager but I'd be surprised if it required a fragment.

Comment: I do see the list view. It just appears over the top of the empty message in the 'TextView'. I'll take a look into the fragments guide. I saw 'OnCreateView' mentioned in another thread and haven't tried using it yet.

Comment: Using `onCreateView` to define the layout to use worked. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.todo_list);` you're telling your activity to display a `ListView` and an empty `TextView`. Your `ListFragment` already contains a `ListView` and empty `TextView` that is managed automatically for you.  So what you are doing is displaying a separate `ListView` from your `todo_list` layout and then modifying the `ListView` contained within your `ListFragment` (which is why it appears that nothing is being loaded into your `ListView`). If you simply remove the call to `getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.todo_list);` it should work as long as you are adding the `ListFragment` properly.

Comment: Removing getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.todo_list); the empty message disappears both when there are items in the list or no items. Otherwise the app still works as expected. I will try using setEmptyView again.

Comment: Combining this with Eluvatar's answer worked. I needed to set the layout inflator to use in `onCreateView`.